# How can I read out the position of element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, document.write

I am trying to program a little task in JavaScript where people can drag and drop two objects on a screen. Here the website: http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/JS/dragdrop.html

My goal is now to read out the end position of both objects. I think I do not really get the name of the element that I want to read out. I have tried the following. After clicking on the button, I only get "null".

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Drag Multiple Elements</title>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-image: url('http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/park.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 7px;
      touch-action: none;
    }

    .item {
      border-radius: 50%;
      touch-action: none;
      user-select: none;
      position: relative;
    }

    .one {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: rgb(245, 230, 99);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: 40%;
      left: -5%;
    }

    .two {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: rgba(196, 241, 190, 1);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: 40%;
      left: -4.8%;
    }

    .three {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: rgb(0, 255, 231);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: -40%;
      left: -5%;
    }

    .four {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: rgb(233, 210, 244);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: -10%;
      left: 5%;
    }

    .item:active {
      opacity: .75;
    }

    .item:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="item one">

      </div>
      <div class="item two">


    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var container = document.querySelector("#container");
    var activeItem = null;

    var active = false;

    container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

    container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

    function dragStart(e) {

      if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        active = true;

        // this is the item we are interacting with
        activeItem = e.target;

        if (activeItem !== null) {
          if (!activeItem.xOffset) {
            activeItem.xOffset = 0;
          }

          if (!activeItem.yOffset) {
            activeItem.yOffset = 0;
          }

          if (e.type === "touchstart") {
            activeItem.initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - activeItem.xOffset;
            activeItem.initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - activeItem.yOffset;
          } else {
            console.log("doing something!");
            activeItem.initialX = e.clientX - activeItem.xOffset;
            activeItem.initialY = e.clientY - activeItem.yOffset;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function dragEnd(e) {
      if (activeItem !== null) {
        activeItem.initialX = activeItem.currentX;
        activeItem.initialY = activeItem.currentY;
      }

      active = false;
      activeItem = null;
    }

    function drag(e) {
      if (active) {
        if (e.type === "touchmove") {
          e.preventDefault();

          activeItem.currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - activeItem.initialX;
          activeItem.currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - activeItem.initialY;
        } else {
          activeItem.currentX = e.clientX - activeItem.initialX;
          activeItem.currentY = e.clientY - activeItem.initialY;
        }

        activeItem.xOffset = activeItem.currentX;
        activeItem.yOffset = activeItem.currentY;

        setTranslate(activeItem.currentX, activeItem.currentY, activeItem);
      }
    }

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

    var xvalitem2= document.getElementById("item.two.yPos");
    var yvalitem2= document.getElementById("item.two.xPos");  
  </script>
</body>


<button type="button" onclick="document.write(xvalitem2)">Try it</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.write(yvalitem2)">Try it</button>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use document.querySelector to get the item, such as

```
document.querySelector('.item.one')
document.querySelector('.item.two')
```

You can use getBoundingClientRect() to get the position of the two elements.
Run the following script in the console or place it after the button element, then after click the buttons, you can see the result on console.

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
['one', 'two'].forEach((v, i) => {
  buttons[i].onclick = null;
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
    let element = document.querySelector(`.item.${v}`);
    let bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(`item ${v} x`, bounding.x);
    console.log(`item ${v} y`, bounding.y);
  });
});
```

By the way, document.write is not a good idea after the document loaded, becasue it will eliminate all the content before.

Also, you can get the position when the dragging ends via dragEnd function, without clicking any button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Drag Multiple Elements</title>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-image: url('http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/park.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 7px;
      touch-action: none;
    }

    .item {
      border-radius: 50%;
      touch-action: none;
      user-select: none;
      position: relative;
    }

    .one {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: rgb(245, 230, 99);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: 40%;
      left: -5%;
    }

    .two {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: rgba(196, 241, 190, 1);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: 40%;
      left: -4.8%;
    }

    .three {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: rgb(0, 255, 231);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: -40%;
      left: -5%;
    }

    .four {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: rgb(233, 210, 244);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      top: -10%;
      left: 5%;
    }

    .item:active {
      opacity: .75;
    }

    .item:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #position {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="item one">

      </div>
      <div class="item two">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="position"></div>
  <script>
    var container = document.querySelector("#container");
    var activeItem = null;
    var oneX, oneY, twoX, twoY;
    ['one', 'two'].forEach((v, i) => {
      let element = document.querySelector(`.item.${v}`);
      let bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      window[`${v}X`] = Math.round(bounding.x);
      window[`${v}Y`] = Math.round(bounding.y);
    });

    var active = false;

    container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

    container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

    function dragStart(e) {

      if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        active = true;

        // this is the item we are interacting with
        activeItem = e.target;

        if (activeItem !== null) {
          if (!activeItem.xOffset) {
            activeItem.xOffset = 0;
          }

          if (!activeItem.yOffset) {
            activeItem.yOffset = 0;
          }

          if (e.type === "touchstart") {
            activeItem.initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - activeItem.xOffset;
            activeItem.initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - activeItem.yOffset;
          } else {
            console.log("doing something!");
            activeItem.initialX = e.clientX - activeItem.xOffset;
            activeItem.initialY = e.clientY - activeItem.yOffset;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function dragEnd(e) {
      if (activeItem !== null) {
        activeItem.initialX = activeItem.currentX;
        activeItem.initialY = activeItem.currentY;
        var bounding = activeItem.getBoundingClientRect();
        window[`${activeItem.classList[1]}X`] = Math.round(bounding.x);
        window[`${activeItem.classList[1]}Y`] = Math.round(bounding.y);
        let position = document.getElementById('position');
        position.innerHTML = `
          <p>oneX: ${oneX}</p>
          <p>oneY: ${oneY}</p>
          <p>twoX: ${twoX}</p>
          <p>twoX: ${twoY}</p>
        `
      }

      active = false;
      activeItem = null;
    }

    function drag(e) {
      if (active) {
        if (e.type === "touchmove") {
          e.preventDefault();

          activeItem.currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - activeItem.initialX;
          activeItem.currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - activeItem.initialY;
        } else {
          activeItem.currentX = e.clientX - activeItem.initialX;
          activeItem.currentY = e.clientY - activeItem.initialY;
        }

        activeItem.xOffset = activeItem.currentX;
        activeItem.yOffset = activeItem.currentY;

        setTranslate(activeItem.currentX, activeItem.currentY, activeItem);
      }
    }

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

    var xvalitem2= document.getElementById("item.two.yPos");
    var yvalitem2= document.getElementById("item.two.xPos");  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chanvin, not sure, but it seems to not work. Is there an easier way by which those values are stored in 4 variables (for both items, the x and y)? Here the current approach: http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/JS/dragdrop.html Thank you!

Comment: The only goal is to have four variables with the position. (I wanted to place this script in a survey and read out what participants do in the task).

Comment: @tobiassch the script element should be placed after the button elements,  in another word, you should move the two button before the script

Comment: Is there a simpler way to create 4 variables?

Comment: @tobiassch Sure, you can define 4 variable and update them in the dragEnd event, and I'll update my anwser to this solution.

Comment: Chanvin, may I ask one more follow up: I want to save the values now in the variables created by my survey, which one works then? The first or the second? v_1805 is one of the variables in the survey. THANKS: document.getElementById("v_1805").value = oneX;
document.getElementById("v_1807").innerHTML = oneX;

Comment: @tobiassch It depends. If v_1805 is a variable, you can just use it to substitute oneX, or use `v_1805 = oneX`; If v_1805 is the id of an input or textarea element, you should use the first one; If v_1805 is the id of an normal element, you should use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `class` attribute not the `id` attribute in both your elements

```
<div class="item one">
<!-- should be -->
<div id="item one">
```

Then you can query it by id

Comment: And, given the above code, how can I read out the x and y values of item two?